# How to read a Jquery $.session.set (plugin) with laravel Session::get() (and if its even possible or a different way to do this)

Tags: php, jquery, session, laravel

I have a problem i don't know how i would pass Session from Jquery to laravel so i can simply use Laravels Session:get(). Here is what i have, I have a div in which are radio buttons and they change on click (they are answers for questions) and on every click i use

```
  $valueOfTheCheckedRadio = $('[name=answer]:checked').val(); 

         $.session.set("val" + $click , $valueOfTheCheckedRadio); //$click is for the current number of question to get
```

And everything works fine i can get answers with $.session.get() in Jquery, but i would like to read that session with laravel. I know i might be doing this entirely wrong but any pointers or help would be appriciated on how i would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't there are no relation between jquery session and php session
but you can use ajax to set a php session

```
function setSession(name,val)
   {
    $.session.set(name ,val); // jquery session
     $.post(your_link,{'val':val,'name': name}, // php or Laravel session
             function(data)
              {

              });
   }
</script>
setSession("val" + $click,$('[name=answer]:checked').val()); // JS
```

in "your_link" php you can retrive name & val of your variable from ajx to set or update your php session

Comment: I will try something like this, you gave me an idea. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Client storage - it is `sessionStorage`, different with php Storage. Use cookie instead.

Comment: Yeah i tought something like that was an issue, thank you for the clarification